# Find duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a large table with the following data on users.

```
social security number
name
address
```

I want to find all possible duplicates in the table
where the ssn is equal but the name is not

My attempt is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table t1
WHERE (SELECT count(*) from Table t2 where t1.name <> t2.name) > 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A grouping on SSN should do it

```
SELECT
   ssn
FROM
   Table t1
GROUP BY
   ssn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

..or if you have many rows per ssn and only want to find duplicate names)

```
...
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
```

Edit, oops, misunderstood

```
SELECT
   ssn
FROM
   Table t1
GROUP BY
   ssn
HAVING MIN(name) <> MAX(name)
```

Comment: your answer seems to give me rows where the name is the same. I want rows where the name is NOT equal

Comment: @Mark: the title says "Find duplicates" which misled me. Corrected.

Comment: I thought i would need self joins. I am loving the min/max idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will handle more than two records with duplicate ssn's:

```
select count(*), name from table t1, (    
    select count(*) ssn_count, ssn 
    from table 
    group by ssn 
    having count(*) > 1
) t2
where t1.ssn = t2.ssn
group by t1.name
having count(*) <> t2.ssn_count
```