# What SQL returns duplicates in first column where values in 2nd column differ?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, duplicates

Question is very similiar to this [find duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057352/find-duplicates-in-sql)
but I'd like to find only those duplicate id with code different than 'ROME' and at least one name is 'ROME'.

I want desired results because:

1. ID is duplicate.
2. At least one origin is 'ROME'

3. Remaining rows for that ID are NOT 'ROME'

```
Table 

ID   ORIGIN
-----------
1    ROME
1    ROME
2    ROME
2    LODI
3    ASTI
4    PISA
4    BARI

Desired Results
ID   ORIGIN
-----------
 2   ROME
 2   LODI
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *remaining rows for that ID are 'not rome'*? If there has to be at least one "ROME" doesn't this make condition 3) obsolete?

Comment: Yes, condition #3 is a redundant expression of condition #2.

Comment: Correction, #3 condition is there to exclude rows having only id='ROME'  ID=1 meets condition #1 and #2 but does not meet #3. That is why I have condition #3. I don't want ID=1

Comment: Check out my answer, I think it does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id,
    origin
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM My_Table T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.id AND T2.origin = 'ROME') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM My_Table T3 WHERE T3.id = T1.id AND T3.origin <> 'ROME')
```

Comment: Although this is a possible solution. It's too hardwired. Can you write it generically for any duplicates? What if he has more than just a conflict with ROME?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.origin FROM Table t0 WHERE t0.id IN
(SELECT distinct(t1.id) FROM Table t1 JOIN Table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id > 
(SELECT t2.id FROM Countries t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name LIMIT 1));
```

Output

2 Rome
2 Lodi

This produced the results you're looking for. I'm not sure if it has any errors for a different data set. But this should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       origin
FROM (
    SELECT id, 
           origin, 
           count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count,
           count(case when origin = 'ROME' then origin else null end) over (partition by id) as rome_count,
           count(case when origin <> 'ROME' then origin else null end) over (partition by id) as non_rome_count,
           row_number() over (partition by id) as rn

    FROM stuff
) t
WHERE rome_count > 0 
  and non_rome_count > 0
  and id_count > 1
```

Comment: Basically this is what I was contemplating before having a look at your answer. But there's too many aggregating here, I think. Perhaps this would be enough: `COUNT(DISTINCT Origin) OVER (...) AS DistinctOrigins, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Origin = 'ROME' THEN 1 END) OVER (...) AS HasTargetOrigin`, then in the outer query: `WHERE DistinctOrigins > 1 AND HasTargetOrigin = 1)`. (Or does Oracle have `COUNT(DISTINCT)` actually?)

Comment: Of course Oracle has `count(distinct)`. As all four windows use the same partition by clause I don't think there is too much overhead involved for doing the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Test
(
    Id int,
    Origin varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT  1,    'ROME' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  1,    'ROME' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2,    'ROME' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2,    'LODI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3,    'ASTI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4,    'PISA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4,    'BARI'

SELECT T.Id, T.Origin FROM #Test T
JOIN Test T2 ON T.Id = T2.Id
WHERE T.Origin = 'ROME' AND T2.Origin != 'ROME' OR T.Origin != 'ROME' AND T2.Origin = 'ROME'
```

It was asked in a comment if this could be written more generically. It cannot, otherwise we would not get the correct results (PISA and BARI would trip the WHERE on Table1.Origin != Table2.Origin)