# Finding specific duplicates when one field is different

Tags: sql

I have a SQL DB table that has some data duplication. I need to find records based on the fact that none of the "duplicate" records has a value of Null value in one of the fields. i.e.

```
ID    Name   StartDate
1     Fred   1/1/1945
2     Jack   2/2/1985
3     Mary   3/3/1999
4     Fred   null 
5     Jack   5/5/1977
6     Jack   4/4/1985
7     Fred   10/10/2001
```

In the example above I need to find Jack and Mary but not Fred. I assume some sort of Self Join or Union but have run into a mental block on what exactly would give me my desired results.

Comment: So you want to find records where COUNT(Name) > 1 and none of those results contain a NULL StartDate?  If you have a single record (`8, Steve, NULL`), it wouldn't be returned?

Comment: This might be useful too:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852246/what-sql-returns-duplicates-in-first-column-where-values-in-2nd-column-differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the query to find duplicates, then add a condition that it not have a record with a NULL `StartDate`

```
SELECT Name
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM myTable WHERE StartDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: The duplicates are a given - John S is looking for one of the records that stands out as a non-duplicate, and then ignoring ALL of the other records related to it (if I understand the question correctly).  The phrase "I need to find Jack and Mary but not Fred" implies that to me, unless I misunderstood the question.  It's the inverse of the "find duplicate records" query.  Your WHERE clause is spot-on (see my answer too) but I'm not sure you need the HAVING COUNT() aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, went back and re-read the question.  It sounds like you need a sub-select instead of a join, although a join would work too.

```
WHERE Name NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM table WHERE StartDate IS NULL )
```

should give the desired results, eliminating ALL Fred records based on the fact that Fred qualified with a single NULL date.

Comment: Will return all but Fred. But he looks for Jack and Mary.

Comment: Just noticed that - I didn't read the question correctly on the first pass.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: first we select all rectords where no field is null, we group them and count them. Then we select just those that have a total > 1

```
select * from (
    select name, startdate, count(*) as total from so group by name, startdate having name is not null and startdate is not null
) as data where total > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of components to this:

1. Selecting Duplicates

this is the easy one.  Depending on your version of SQL, you basically do:

```
 select count(*) as numbers, Name from this_table having numbers >= 2 group by Name
```

2. Removing those with Null

This one increases complexity, but ultimately isn't bad.

```
 select count(*) as numbers, Name from this_table  where StartDate is not null having numbers >= 2 group by Name
```

3. Dealing with duplicates that are also null
   This is a case not mentioned in your original question.  Say I have someone with three entires, two are dates but one is null.   Do we want these records, or not?  If we do, then the query in part 2 works.  If we do not, then we want a sub-select, like:

   select count(*) as numbers, Name from this_table where Name not in (select Name from this_table where StartDate is null) having numbers >= 2 group by Name

That said, these queries are not very useful unless you have something more uniquely identifying than a name.  First names especially are overly common.