# Native SQL , generic duplicate entries retrieval

Tags: sql

I have a table T with fields `f1` , `f2` and `f3`.

I would like to retrieve every `f1` which belongs to the row with duplicate `f2` and `f3` fields. How can this be done ?

Edit :

Such as for :

```
(1,2,3) 
(2,2,3) 
(4,1,1) 
(2,2,2) 
(3,4,3) 
(1,5,6)
```

Expected result being :

```
(1)
(2)
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please post some sample data. How do you want your output to look?

Comment: Asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicates+in+table+sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find duplicates in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057352/find-duplicates-in-sql)

Comment: The question has lack of details. Do you want some kind of `distinct` or `order by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select f1 from T group by (f1) having (count(f2) > 1 and count(f3) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will bring back every f1 value that is on a row where the f2 and f3 values appear on multiple rows.

```
select T.f1 from T
inner join (select f2,f3 from T group by f2,f3 having count(*) > 1) dups
on t.f2 = dups.f2 and t.f3 = dups.f3;
```

So if you have the data.

```
f1 f2 f3
-- -- --
1  A  b
2  A  c
3  A  b
4  B  b
```

You'd get back 1 & 3.